# Read cookies from within a Service Worker?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I would like to read a cookie within my service worker to use it when setting up my caches, but can't find any way of doing it.

Is there any way of doing that, or will I need to duplicate cookie data into IDB or similar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, you can't access them. There's a [discussion in the W3C ServiceWorker repo](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/707) about adding methods to access them in the future.

Comment: They have now published a draft for a new spec called CookieStore that covers that use case https://wicg.github.io/cookie-store/