# Why can't serviceworker access cookies

Tags: cookies, service-worker

As per as i know **Service Workers** can not access the cookies. Because of this i am facing a lot of problems in implementing SW for my site.

I want to know what are the reasons, that **Service Workers** can not access the cookies.Right now I am using messaging to convey the cookie content to **Service Workers**.
Is there any better way or hack to do it more efficiently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read cookies from within a Service Worker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447567/read-cookies-from-within-a-service-worker)

Answer (score 8):

There is no reason. Some use cases have been proposed and a [new API is under development](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/837). Sure your use case and insights are useful in the conversation if they are not covered yet.

You could use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) to a client to request the cookies and send it to the service worker.