# Make progressive web app to load only after pubcookie validation

Tags: apache, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a application which is cached using service worker. So when a user hits the url it get loaded directly from browser.

But now I have to implement Apache sso pubcookie validation, i.e., Application should load only if it has valid cookie added by apache.

How can I stop loading application from service worker if it doesn't have pubcookie and redirect sso page.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't access cookies from within Service Workers. See [Read cookies from within a Service Worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447567/read-cookies-from-within-a-service-worker)

I think the better solution would be to have the client code itself handle pubcookie checking and if it doesn't pass, it can cancel rendering the app.

Comment: @abaraham Could you elaborate how to activate service worker only after pubcookie validation because my understanding is if service worker is running then It will load the website instantly and we don't have control over it.

Comment: You need to update your service worker to evict the cache entry for index. Now your index should not be the main entry point for you application but contains only the validation code. If validation passes, make the page to redirect itself to the entry point.