# How does Service Worker handle cookies?

Tags: caching, cookies, service-worker

I know [Service Worker doesn't have access to cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447567/read-cookies-from-within-a-service-worker) yet, but how are cookies proxied when pages are served from SW [caches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)? If I invalidate a cookie or change its value outside of the page and then try to read it from JavaScript inside the page, will I get the old value or the new value?

If there was a `Set-Cookie:` header in the response, will that get stored in the cache? Will that header be replayed and go into effect each time the response was read from cache?

The [MDN documentation for the Cache interface says nothing about cookies](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1340310), and neither does the [W3C SW spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#cache).

Comment: almost a year passed and hardly no new answer to this one, they say `Service Worker` is a hit, huh?