# Service worker: caching POST requests with IndexedDB - security concerns

Tags: javascript, security, caching, service-worker, indexeddb

Correct me if I'm wrong but I feel like every single article about service workers I have read, covers only one use-case: very simple, "static" website. Like "Here, you can cache your images using SW and now your app can work offline. The end.".

Well... I have an existing app, let's say it's a "TODO-list": user logs in and can view/modify the list. Server communication is based on POST requests (JSON).

Now, I want to make it work offline: user should be able to still view the list (this time from cache).
**Its pretty easy to cache POST requests using IndexedDB but how do it securely?** Lists can contain sensitive data and if not encrypted, everyone could just open DevTools and browse them.

Any tips, ideas? I need at least some level of security.
My first -not a bright- idea was to encrypt the cached data using user's credentials but that wouldn't work: credentials are known only when loggin in and are lost after page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

How about encrypting cached data with session id (from cookie)?
If user logs out or if session (cookie) expire - cookie is deleted and the decryption key is lost.

However, according to [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/356265/what-do-browsers-do-with-expired-cookies#comment640132_356267):

> Yeah, some firefox versions seem to conserve expired cookies forever.
>   I just deleted some cookies from my Firefox which expired in April
>   2012. (There were newer cookies with same domain and name, though.)

I know, the comment is old (2013) but still a bit worrying

Comment: Won't work either, you can't access cookie from a service worker:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447567/read-cookies-from-within-a-service-worker